# Mongo aggregation for match where difference between two array values is between X and Y

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My data in an aggregation has results that currently is an array of objects like this:

```
[{
  _id: {
    _id: ObjectId("111111111"),
    userref: "aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaa"
  },
  data: [{
    fruit: "Apples",
    count: 10
  }, {
    fruit: "Pears",
    count: 20
  }, {
    fruit: "Grapefruits",
    count: 2
  }]
},
{
  _id: {
    _id: ObjectId("222222222"),
    userref: "bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb"
  },
  data: [{
    fruit: "Apples",
    count: 5
  }, {
    fruit: "Grapefruits",
    count: 10
  }]
}]
```

I now need to match only those users who have an abs(Apples-Pears) count between given values X and Y.
ie the first record has a difference between count of Apples and Pears of 10. If X = 1 and Y = 50, then the record would match. If X = 1 and Y = 9, the record would not match. The second record would not match in either case because it does not have an entry for Pears.

Could someone help out with this part of the aggregation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {//filtering with both entries
      "$and": [
        {
          "data.fruit": "Apples"
        },
        {
          "data.fruit": "Pears"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {//reshaping to get the counts
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $project: {//creating a variable to get the counts
      "appleCount": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$data.fruit",
              "Apples"
            ]
          },
          then: "$data.count",
          else: 0
        }
      },
      "pearsCount": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$data.fruit",
              "Pears"
            ]
          },
          then: "$data.count",
          else: 0
        }
      },
      "data": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "data": {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      appleCount: {//only one apple entry - so it is valid
        $sum: "$appleCount"
      },
      pearsCount: {//similarly
        $sum: "$pearsCount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 1,
      data: 1,
      "isValid": {
        "$cond": {//returns true with the expected difference
          "if": {
            "$gte": [
              10,
              {
                "$abs": {
                  "$subtract": [
                    "$appleCount",
                    "$pearsCount"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "then": true,
          "else": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NqU3pkyBk3s)

You have to filter out only `true` values from the doc using `$match` as mentioned in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/85Q0jk7opr-)